# If $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ are homeomorphic to a subgraph of $G\circ e$, then they are homeomorphic to a subgraph of $G$.

Tags: graph-theory

I have to proof the following:

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and $e\in E$. If $G\circ e$ (contraction of $e$) contains a subgraph that is homeomorphic to $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$, then $G$ contains a subgraph that is homeomorphic to $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.

My idea is to show that $G\circ e$ is a topological minor of $G$. But I don't know how to start. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Let me proof the question for you. "Homeomorph" is a noun, and not usually used in mathematics. You probably mean "homeomorphic". There. I have proofed it. Did you by any chance want to *prove* the statement, instead?

Comment: Can you use Kuratowski's theorem? If so, it is easy: If $G\circ e$ is not planar, then $G$ cannot be planar either.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I am also interested in the solution, but have not had Kuratowski's Theorem yet. With which tools / which idea would you tackle the problem? I don't have a clue and don't really know where to start.

Comment: Note that the forbidden subgraph in $G$ will not necessarily be of the same kind as the forbidden subgraph in $G\circ e$: For example, it is possible that $G\circ e$ is $K_5$ itself, but $G$ doesn't have enough degree-4 vertices to embed $K_5$. In that case there will be an embedding of $K_{3,3}$ into $G$, though $K_{3,3}$ does not embed into $G\circ e$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Here is something stronger you can prove, with fewer distractions:

> Assume that $H$ is a (not necessarily topological) minor of $G$. Then --
>
> - If $K_{3,3}$ embeds homeomorphically into $H$, then $K_{3,3}$ embeds homeomorphically into $G$, and
> - If $K_5$ embeds homeomorphically into $H$ but $K_5$ *does not* embed homeomorphically into $G$, then $K_{3,3}$ embeds homeomorphically into $G$.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "embeds homeomorphically"?

Comment: @MPB94: The same as "is homeomorphic to a subgraph".

Comment: Do you have a hint how to tackle this claim?